# Is the SUBJECT_ID filed in the dataset the same as the PRODUCT_ID?

Tags: releasing-data

Is the SUBJECT_ID filed in the dataset same as the PRODUCT_ID as noted in downloadable datasheets at
http://www.trustlet.org/extended_epinions.html